# getting error while accessing login page in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a login page using firebase but i am not able to sign in a user after registering the user .
Below is the code

MainActivity.java

```
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  String email = emailText.getText().toString();
                  String pwd = passwordText.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter Email Id",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pwd)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (pwd.length()<5){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Password should be atleast 5 character long",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(task.getException()));

                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });
```

LogCat

```
04-16 09:13:48.974 12052-12106/com.example.ashish.internchat I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-16 09:13:55.253 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=2 eventTime = 2883907 downTime = 2883907 title= com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.SignupActivity
04-16 09:13:55.375 12052-12063/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ActivityThreadEui: schedulePauseActivity com.example.ashish.internchat.SignupActivity finished=false userLeaving=true configChanges=0 dontReport=false
04-16 09:13:55.408 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ActivityThreadEui: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{d0d9914 token=android.os.BinderProxy@ce675bd {com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.MainActivity}} startsNotResumed=false
04-16 09:13:55.411 12052-12103/com.example.ashish.internchat I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-16 09:13:56.085 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=3 eventTime = 2884740 downTime = 2884740 title= com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.MainActivity
04-16 09:13:57.467 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=1 eventTime = 2886124 downTime = 2886124 title= com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.MainActivity
04-16 09:13:58.974 12052-12097/com.example.ashish.internchat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-16 09:13:59.226 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=1 eventTime = 2887882 downTime = 2887882 title= com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.MainActivity
04-16 09:14:15.535 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=2 eventTime = 2904191 downTime = 2904191 title= com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.MainActivity
04-16 09:14:23.003 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=1 eventTime = 2911659 downTime = 2911659 title= com.example.ashish.internchat/com.example.ashish.internchat.MainActivity
04-16 09:14:23.140 12052-12097/com.example.ashish.internchat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-16 09:14:23.142 12052-12097/com.example.ashish.internchat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-16 09:14:23.939 12052-12052/com.example.ashish.internchat E/MainActivity: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The email address is badly formatted.
04-16 09:14:33.222 12052-12097/com.example.ashish.internchat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

everytime the user clicks sign in it shows failed whether the user enters correct data or wrong

Comment: post your logcat please!

Answer (score 0):

never mind , it was error from mine side only . When the user sign up i was directly sending the user to login activity without signing out the user .

Answer (score 0):

follow [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

and for your code delete this line 
                            finish();

also you can add :

```
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```